# Referencing classes generated by annotation processor

Tags: java, gwt, annotation-processing

I am working on a gwt project using a modified version of the activities and places pattern. I have created an annotation and an annotation processor that will generate the activity mapper based on activity classes that have been annotated. But I don't know the correct way to reference the generated class in my existing source code. What is the correct way to reference the generated classes since they don't exist until compile time?

Comment: You should just be able to refer to them by name, and when the code is compiled it will run the annotation processor first and then let you refer to the newly generated classes.

Comment: Doh!  Yes that works just fine. My issue was getting the processor correctly configured. Thanks Louis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to refer to them by name, and when the code is compiled it will run the annotation processor first and then let you refer to the newly generated classes.

Comment: before compiler run, IDE will report no class def error, right?